# HTTP get requests in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am pretty new to javascript where I am trying with ajax to make an get request. I am trying to get the password from the response.

Javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LoginUser").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://website/api/user/Mikkel1337',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',

            error: function () {
                alert("An error had occurred");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data);

                alert(jsonStr['password']);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

The response JSON code looks like this:

```
{"userId":16,"firstName":"mojn","lastName":"mojn","email":"mojn@mojn.dk","accountName":"Mikkel1337","password":"123","userRoleId":1,"active":false,"userRole":null,"competetion":[],"judge":[],"team":[]}
```

When im running this I only get the error function. Any suggestions or solution is appreciated :)

Comment: If you check the network tab of the console you should be able to see what the error returned from the request is. That will help you diagnose the problem

Comment: Was that JSON really included in the response?  How do you know? Your error function didn't tell you that.

Comment: When I have the console open in chrome, this is the only error message I get "[Violation] 'load' handler took 2006ms".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are converting the JSON to string and trying to access the string as object. Please don't stringify the data, and for JSON why using long code, your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LoginUser").click(function () {
        $.getJSON( "http://website/api/user/Mikkel1337", function( data ) {
            // do something on success
            alert(data.password);
        });
    });
});
```

Cheers !!!

Comment: Although you have spotted a bug.... it's not the same bug the OP asked about.  The success function isn't even being called.

Comment: Then it means there is something wrong on the page where the AJAX request is sent.

Comment: When im running the code with only use of an button the code works, but when im trying to run it after I have submitted an form, I get the alert "An error had occurred"

Answer (score 0):

dont need to JSON.stringify of data simple use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#LoginUser").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://website/api/user/Mikkel1337',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',

        error: function () {
            alert("An error had occurred");
        },
        success: function (data) {


            alert(data.password);
        }
    });
});
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You should pass two argument for error:function(jqXHR, exception) as below.

And check once your API Url using proper way, may be your API is not show you proper result and you not get any of data from that API so that may be a reason you get error message.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#LoginUser").click(function () {         
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://website/api/user/Mikkel1337',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(data); 
                    //also try this way to get JSON data:
                    // var jsonStr =JSON.parse(data);   
                    alert(jsonStr['password']);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                        alert("An error had occurred");
                },
            });
        });
    });
```